# Filtering & Sorting Firebase (Firestore) Data on a Flutter App

Tags: firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter

If my user database is on Firestore and on Registration I ask each users a set of few questions (checkboxes, radio buttons, etc). I want to create a Filter and Sort mechanism where a user is able to filter and sort a list of other users (from Firestore) based on **multiple filter parameters sorted according to a particular field**.

Is what I want to create even possible on Firebase (FireStore) and Flutter or do I need anything else?

Can anybody please link me to any relating Flutter/Firebase documentation, YouTube videos, or any other relevant content.

Answer (score 1):

Once you fetch your list of users from Firestore, you can easily sort and filter them using the methods provided by the `List` class in Flutter:

`sort` method for sorting: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/List/sort.html

`retainWhere` method for filtering: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/List/retainWhere.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create multiple filter and ordering in firestore in flutter app.

```
 QuerySnapshot orderQuerySnapshot = await orderCollection
            .where("status", isEqualTo: status)
            .where("timestamp", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: lowerDate)
            .where("timestamp", isLessThanOrEqualTo: upperDate)
            .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
            .get();
```